Factors that influenced the establishment of Galois theory
I have recently become interested in Galois theory, as I have recently asked about it on Mathematics Stack Exchange. As in this question, I was curious about the meaning of "maximally" breaks the symmetry, and I learned that it was about roots that are substituted into non-symmetric equations for n variables. But this time, I have a new question. If you look at the part written by Alain Connes in the book Les Déchiffreurs - Voyage en mathématiques,

When his predecessors were finding the symmetrical function of the roots of the equation, Galois began to break the symmetry to see the problem more clearly. His starting point was to arbitrarily choose a symmetrical function of the roots that did not tolerate symmetry. What is surprising is that the invariant deduced in the process of going from the function to the roots is actually unrelated to the arbitrary choice he made at the beginning.

I'm curious about [His starting point was to arbitrarily choose a symmetrical function of the roots that did not tolerate symmetry. What is surprising is that the invariant deduced in the process of going from the function to the roots is actually unrelated to the arbitrary choice he made at the beginning.] in this paragraph. In the actual history of mathematics, I'm curious about what influence breaking symmetry had on the establishment of Galois theory in the process of Galois establishing the great achievement of Galois theory, and what [What is surprising is that the invariant deduced in the process of going from the function to the roots is actually unrelated to the arbitrary choice he made at the beginning.] means mathematically.
Edit

For a cubic $f(x)$, We investigate the quantity $p(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1 + \omega x_2 + \omega^2 x_3$ where $\omega$ is the cube root of unity, observing it takes six values given the six permutations of $x_1, x_2, x_3$.

I think the meaning of the invariant from the book Les Déchiffreurs - Voyage en mathématiques is this formula $p(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1 + \omega x_2 + \omega^2 x_3$. Is this thinking correct?
